# How can I compare two integer columns in two different jtables, and then print greater or lesser in another jtable by clicking button?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

I am still developing stock management system with netbeans ide using java. In one interface I have three different jtables, one for current materials quantity in stock, one for required materials quantity for fulfill order, and other one for print is the quantity in stock is greater or lesser than the quantity in order. How can I compare this two quantity columns and print results?

/***
these are the codes tried till now
****/

//global variables

```
Vector v=new Vector();
Object listOrder=new Object();
Vector v1=new Vector();
Object listOrder1=new Object();
Vector v2=new Vector();
Object listOrder2=new Object();
int tranval[];
int stkval[];
```

//button action for import database values to tables

```
private void RequiredActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     tranval =new int[20];
     stkval =new int[20];
    try{
        ResultSet rs = new getMatierialDataM().searchItems("SELECT icode,qty from transactiono where oid ='"+jComboBox2_oid.getSelectedItem()+"'");

//define tables 
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2_required.getModel(); //required materials
        dtm.setRowCount(0);
        Vector v = null;
        DefaultTableModel dtm1 = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1_availability.getModel();
        dtm1.setRowCount(0); //available materials in stock
        Vector v1 =null;

        while(rs.next()){
            String ico=rs.getString("icode");
            String q1=rs.getString("qty");
            int q11=Integer.parseInt(q1);
            ResultSet rs1 = new getMatierialDataM().searchItems("SELECT transactionbom.mid,transactionbom.qty,component.comid,matierial.stockqty from transactionbom,component,matierial where transactionbom.icode ='"+ico+"' AND transactionbom.icode=component.icode AND transactionbom.mid=matierial.mid");
            int len=0;

            while(rs1.next()){
            String q2=rs1.getString("qty");
            int q22=Integer.parseInt(q2);
            int qty =q11*q22;       //calculation 
            String cid,mid,stq;
            cid=rs1.getString("comid");
            mid=rs1.getString("mid");
            stq=rs1.getString("stockqty");

            tranval[len]=qty;
            stkval[len]=q22;
            len++;

        v = new Vector();
            v.add(cid);
            v.add(mid);
            v.add(qty);
            dtm.addRow(v);

        v1 = new Vector();
            v1.add(cid);
            v1.add(mid);
            v1.add(stq);
            dtm1.addRow(v1);
        }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Logger.getLogger(ItemCosting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}


//button action for compare above two tables and get stock status in third table

private void jButton1_checkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultTableModel dtm1 = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1_status.getModel();
    dtm1.setRowCount(0);
    Vector v2 =null;
    int x=0;
    int y=3;
    int len=jTable1_availability.getRowCount();

    v2 = new Vector();
    while(x<len){
        if(tranval[x]>stkval[x]){
            v2.add("mid");
            v2.add("OK");
        }else{
            v2.add("mid");
            v2.add("NO");
        }
        dtm1.addRow(v2);
        tranval[x]++;
        stkval[x]++;
        x++;
    }
}
```

That above codes print only one same result in all rows in third table.
I expected some NO status in few rows but is prints OK in all of the rows.

Comment: Hint: don't use the vector class. Use List and ArrayList. Also learn about "raw generic types" and why you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Currently I have no idea about these techniques. But I will try its.

Comment: I also suggest you seriously change the way how you name your variables. These names help human readers to understand what the source code intends to do. Your excessive use of one character names achieves the exact opposite, it basically makes your code 10 times harder to read than it ought to be...